# Including spaces in Scanner in java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am writing a simple code that takes number,name,surname from the user with scanner.
But when user enters name with spaces in it(two or more names) the  code thinks string after the first space is surname.
I tried using `input.nextLine();` in that case it skipped name completely and took only surname from the user.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number");
int num = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Name");
String name = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter Surname");
String surname = input.next();
```

Comment: Get the complete line from input and trim the spaces. That's the best practise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number");
int num=input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // add this
System.out.println("Enter Name");
String name=input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Surname");
String surname=input.nextLine();
System.out.println(num + " - " + name + " - " + surname);
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter number
1
Enter Name
user name
Enter Surname
sur name
1 - user name - sur name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **sc.nextLine()** instead of **sc.next()** to read String with spaces